# About the use of "over" in "He is going to hold America's infrastructure hostage over the investigation issue."

Tags: usage

The seventh entry in the ODE defines the preposition *over* as:

> On the subject of.

along with some synonyms:

> in connection with, regarding, concerning, about.

Is this the meaning that *over* took within:

> He is going to hold America's infrastructure hostage **over** the investigation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means "**in connection with** the investigation issue" or in this specific case "**because of** the investigation issue".